# Select unique value from the results

Tags: mysql, sql

```
sap_article_id
100262
100262
100262
100262
136151
100262
141933
136151
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
141933
141933
136151
141933
141933
100262
141933
100262
100262
136151
100262
100262
100262
100262
141933
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
136151
100262
100262
100262
141933
141933
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
141933
141933
141933
100262
100262
100262
100262
138910
100262
100262
100262
100262
100262
138910
138910
```

I want unique values order in

```
100262
136151
141933
138910
```

This is my query, when I use `GROUP BY` the order has changed:

```
SELECT sap_article_id 
FROM order_requisition ore 
INNER JOIN order_requisition_grouping org ON org.group_id=ore.group_id 
WHERE sap_vendor_id=10483 
ORDER BY modified_ship_date;
```

Comment: Show the work what you have done and not just what you want.

Comment: Please **edit the question** instead of adding your code in the comments. Also, from the code you've posted I can tell that you're [not using a MVCE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` Or `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT sap_article_id FROM Table_Name GROUP BY sap_article_id
```

**OR**

```
SELECT DISTINCT sap_article_id FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: select sap_article_id from order_requisition ore inner join order_requisition_grouping org on org.group_id=ore.group_id where sap_vendor_id=10483 order by modified_ship_date;

Comment: This is my query, when i using group by the order has changed

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding comments on answers @SatishKumar.

Comment: @SatishKumar Use Distinct

Comment: distinct didnt give order i want

Comment: Add data for `modified_ship_date` column and Explain your question properly

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT sap_article_id
FROM TableName 
ORDER BY sap_article_id ASC
```